# Can't Load Image Into Android App

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I'm really new to Android coding, so please don't yell at me >.<

I'm following an online guide, explaining me how to code an Android game. Although I'm stuck at loading images, I just can't get it right.

I use IntelliJ Idea as my IDE. The way all the directories are sorted by default can be seen in the following picture:
[image: Folders Layout]

I drew a very ugly mess on Paint and added it to the directories using [this guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/creating-image-assets.html?origin=old_help). It did something with my image and added a menu.png file into each directory.

In the code, I'm trying to load the image with the AssetManager with the .open() method using the string "menu.png" (The AssetManager is gotten from the main Activity using the getAssets() method). However, I keep getting an IO exception, and I have no idea how to fix it. I looked on several guides online, yet I still can't pull this off. Help me please!

P.S. I'm not a native speaker, so sorry for my English.
Thanks everyone and have a nice day!

Comment: IT is not humanistic science. You do not talk what you code does. You show your code. We can read it.

Comment: There isn't much to show though. All that's relevant is using assets.open("menu.png"); where assets is the AssetManager gotten from getAssets() on the main event. I'm getting an IO exception. The thing is I'm not sure where/how to put my menu image.

Comment: read the doc: https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html

Comment: I've been digging through the docs. I tried adding a new folder named assets and putting my picture in it, and it worked!
It seems like the AssetManager looks for that specific folder. How could I use the default folder made and managed by IntelliJ? (the res folder with all the sub-folders in it, as seen in the above picture)

Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: Don't use `mipmaps`, use `drawable`, instead. `mipmaps` should **only and exclusively** contain the **app icon**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load an image, you need to use an Android intent that will get you to the default image loader app (given by the phone manufacturer).

First create the intent. This should be when the user clicks a button, or a similar event.

 
`// Creates an Intent to pick a photo
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);`

Then execute the intent:

`// ARGS: the intent, a key to access later
startActivityForResult(i, 1);`

You have to now set a `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` (detailed instructions available [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)).
Here is some sample code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        try {
            // Do whatever you want with this bitmap (image)
            Bitmap bitmapImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
            Log.i("Image Path", selectedImage.getPath());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

That's it! Do whatever you want with the created Bitmap. Remember, this method goes directly into your class.

Comment: Thanks alot! For all the time you invested and your help! :)

Comment: No problem, glad it helped!